# Array of arrays confusion

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have an array of comma delimited string. I turn that into an array of arrays by splitting out the csvs.  It looks okay in my loop (from the output), giving me an array of  strings.  However, after I add the array of strings to another array, it seems to get messed up.

Output at the end shows a character from a string, not an actual string.

```
 foreach($n in $Names) 
    {

    $obj = ([string]$n.value).Split(",")
    "0: " + $obj[0]
    "1: " + $obj[1]
    #$obj.GetTYpe()
    $arrInfo+= $obj
    }

$arrinfo[5][0]
$arrinfo[5][1]

$a = $arrinfo[5]
$a[0]
$a[1]
```

Output looks something like:
0: Item 0 string
1: Item 1 string

....
I
t
I
t
What is going wrong?  Why is my second array (arrInfo) seem to have just strings instead of an array of strings?

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a little more, I changed the line to read:  $arrinfo += , $obj and it works as expected. I don't fully understand why.